# TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'

Tags: python, jupyter, telegram-bot

i keep getting an error so am not sure how to go about this.this is my first time making a bot

```
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, CallbackContext

nest_asyncio.apply()

async def start(update, context):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.message.chat_id, text="Hello, I'm a bot!")

async def main():
    bot_token = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE'
    updater = Updater(token=bot_token, use_context=True)

    # Register your handlers
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

    # Start the bot
    await updater.start_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())
```

but i keep getting this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [3], in <cell line: 20>()
     18     await updater.start_polling()
     20 if __name__ == '__main__':
---> 21     asyncio.run(main())

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py:35, in _patch_asyncio.<locals>.run(main, debug)
     33 task = asyncio.ensure_future(main)
     34 try:
---> 35     return loop.run_until_complete(task)
     36 finally:
     37     if not task.done():

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\nest_asyncio.py:89, in _patch_loop.<locals>.run_until_complete(self, future)
     86 if not f.done():
     87     raise RuntimeError(
     88         'Event loop stopped before Future completed.')
---> 89 return f.result()

File ~\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\futures.py:201, in Future.result(self)
    199 self.__log_traceback = False
    200 if self._exception is not None:
--> 201     raise self._exception
    202 return self._result

File ~\anaconda3\lib\asyncio\tasks.py:256, in Task.__step(***failed resolving arguments***)
    252 try:
    253     if exc is None:
    254         # We use the `send` method directly, because coroutines
    255         # don't have `__iter__` and `__next__` methods.
--> 256         result = coro.send(None)
    257     else:
    258         result = coro.throw(exc)

Input In [3], in main()
     10 async def main():
     11     bot_token = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE'
---> 12     updater = Updater(token=bot_token, use_context=True)
     14     # Register your handlers
     15     updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'token'
```

so i was like lets me remove the token in:

`updater = Updater(token=bot_token, use_context=True)`

so its:

`updater = Updater(bot_token, use_context=True)`

then i got another problem:

`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'use_context'`

so what did i do next....i removed the `use_context parameter=True`

but now its giving this error:

```
Input In [5], in main()
     10 async def main():
     11     bot_token = 'YOUR_BOT_TOKEN_HERE'
---> 12     updater = Updater(bot_token)
     14     # Register your handlers
     15     updater.dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'update_queue'
```

so im not sure what is wrong ive searched everywhere i cant find a solution...so tell me whats wrong and also if you find any code that might cause a problem even after this current problem is solved please tel me so that i dont keep coming here....or maybe if my whole approach is wrong from the start...

edit: so i couldnt find a way to send a code as a reply but somone asked if i wanted to use th async way..but i was using this code before:

```py
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hello, I'm your bot!")

bot_token = 'bot_token'

bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)
updater = Updater(bot_token, use_context=True)


dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

start_handler = CommandHandler('start', start)

dispatcher.add_handler(start_handler)

updater.start_polling()
```

then i used this:

```py
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler
import queue

def start(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Hello, I'm your bot!")
    
bot_token = 'your_bot_token'

bot = telegram.Bot(token=bot_token)
updater = Updater(bot_token, use_context=True, workers=0)

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

dispatcher.add_handler(CommandHandler('start', start))

updater.start_polling()
```

Comment: are you sure that you can use `telegram.ext` in async way?

Comment: @A D so i wasnt using this async way before but check the post i editted it by adding the codes i was using before